# Парсинг fl.ru при помощи python (bs4, requests), как отделить категории при парсинге?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Запускаю парсинг заказов на фл.ру таким способом:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('https://www.fl.ru/projects/')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

def Save():
    with open('listfile.txt', 'a') as filehandle:  
        for listitem in orders:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)

items = html.find_all('div', class_='b-post')
orders = []
for item in items:
    orders.append({
        'title': item.find('a', class_='b-post__link').get_text(strip=True),
        })

print(orders)
Save()
```

Помогите разобраться, как парсить только заказы из определенной категории (тексты, дизайн и т.д.)?

Answer (score 0):

Смысл его парсить, если у него есть

```
print(requests.get('https://www.fl.ru/rss/all.xml?category=5').text)
```